# При добавлении данных в DataGridView вместо русских символов знак вопроса

Tags: c#, база-данных, visual-studio-2015, datagridview

Строка подключения

```
String ConnStr = "Data Source=;Integrated Security=True; Timeout=30";
```

если вставить Charset=utf8
выдает ошибку System.ArgumentException: "Ключевое слово не поддерживается: "charset"."

Comment: Если изменить данные через конструктор таблиц, то все нормально отображается

Comment: А когда вы данные считали, то в деьаггере они нормально отображаются или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9381861/4244707):

```
var dbEnc = Encoding.UTF8;
var uniEnc = Encoding.Unicode;
byte[] dbBytes = dbEnc.GetBytes(dbString);
byte[] uniBytes = Encoding.Convert(dbEnc, uniEnc, dbBytes);
string msg = uniEnc.GetString(uniBytes);
```

Строки в C# в формате `UNICODE`.